# How to get extension service_worker (Background page) object in WebdriverIO

Tags: google-chrome-extension, webdriver-io

I am new to WebdriverIO.

I want test my browser extension using WebdriverIO, I am able to install extension using .crx file, but I want to get control over the extension to execute few tests.

**Extension Install Code: (config.js)
**

```
capabilities: [
    {
      maxInstances: 5,
      browserName: "chrome",
      "goog:chromeOptions": {
        args: ["disable-popup-blocking", "allow-insecure-localhost"],
        extensions: [
          require("fs").readFileSync("/path/extension_file.crx").toString("base64"),
        ],
      },
      acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    },
```

Thank you in advance

I tried to open extension popup and get control of the it but that did not work as I am not able to open extension popup programmatically (Using Chrome API & WebdriverIO). Also, I am not sure how to configure the browser to have access to the background page (or service).
I went through the WebdriverIO documentation as well the Chrome API documentation and since both of it did not work posting this here!

***Expected behaviour***
*After the installation :*

1. To be able to launch the extension pop up after installation
2. To get access to the extension background page (or service worker)

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar. You can open the extensions page by navigating to chrome://extensions, but it doesn't seem that you can interact with anything under the <extensions-manager> element (where the background link is to open the extension window).

I also tried navigating directly to the chrome extension url, but that didn't work.